# Python : SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, ios, dictionary

Not sure where the issue is, i tried using multiple variables names to this dict with the same error:

```
>>> hostname=dict('172.16.1.75'='N-Switch', '172.16.1.76' = 'W-Switch', '172.16.1.77' = 'E-Switch')
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

I am trying to create a dictionary for a script to change hostnames on assets based by calling their IP address as the key. any idea where the issue is?

Comment: To use the `dict` function, the keys must be passed as you would function parameters, meaning they must be valid indetifiers

Comment: You can only use valid Python identifiers as keyword arguments (including to the `dict()` callable). Use a `{...}` dict display instead.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390606/python-syntaxerror-with-dict1-but-1-works

Comment: Can someone provide an example, if I want to achieve this with `dict` ?

Answer (score 3):

The usual format for initiallizing a dict is like this

```
hostname=dict([('172.16.1.75','N-Switch'), ('172.16.1.76','W-Switch'), ('172.16.1.77', 'E-Switch')])
```

or more simply as given by Carles Mitjans in his answer (which appears to have been delete so adding the gist of it here for the benefit of < 10k users)

```
 hostname={'172.16.1.75':'N-Switch', '172.16.1.76' : 'W-Switch', '172.16.1.77' : 'E-Switch'}
```

This is in fact the more usual way of using dictionaries in python. The `dict` built in is used only when you are working with dynamic lists.

Also possible is a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: I think you're missing a parent container for the tuples

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you are using valid syntax, try:

```
hostname={'172.16.1.75':'N-Switch', '172.16.1.76' : 'W-Switch', '172.16.1.77' : 'E-Switch'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, parameters can't be strings. The solution would be to create a dictionary using `{}` constructor:

```
hostname={'172.16.1.75':'N-Switch', '172.16.1.76' : 'W-Switch', '172.16.1.77' : 'E-Switch'}
```

If you wish to use the `dict` constructor you need to provide valid parameters as keys (not strings).